# Unsupported connection option " INIT "

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, init

I don't understand what the problem is and how to view it. second month in programming

1 location error

```
private static String dbUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:test; INIT = RUNSCRIPT FROM classpath:init.sql' ";`
```

2 text error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: >org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Неподдерживаемая >опция соединения " INIT "

> Unsupported connection setting " INIT " [90113-200]

3 possible cause of the error

[image]

Comment: It seems you have a typo on the url, try `"jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM classpath:init.sql";`

Comment: As well as removing the extra whitespaces, this needs the classpath file to be in single quotes, in order to work (for me): `"jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init.sql'";`. @YoucefLAIDANI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static String dbUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init.sql'";
```

Note the removal of specific whitespaces from the example in the question (`...;INIT=RUNSCRIPT ...`), and the use of single quotes around `'classpath:init.sql'` (the question is missing one of the single quotes).

See the [RUNSCRIPT](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#runscript) documentation for examples, including:

> RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/com/acme/test.sql'